# Find out the number of clients connected in x11vnc

Tags: vnc, x11vnc

I am developing an application that uses x11vnc in the background and I would like to know how many users are currently connected. I have reviewed the list of commands but I have not found anything for that purpose.

Any ideas?

Comment: This looks like it might provide some insight... https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94711/how-many-remote-users

Comment: Thank you! I finally used this code:
`netstat -anpt | grep SERVER_PORT | grep 'ESTABLISHED' | grep -c 'tcp'`

That is, filters the number of connections established with my VNC server (usually SERVER_PORT is 5900) and then counts the number of times that "tcp" appers in these results (which is 1 per client).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next interface

```
x11vnc -query client_count -display :0
```